# Diffences between PHP 5.3.x and 5.4.x when using end() function

Tags: php, arrays

I am running PHP 5.3.28 and it return error

```
if(strcmp($text,end($arrayText)["key"]) == 0){
    ..do something...
}
```

I change to the following code, which works just fine:

```
$lastArrayText = end($arrayText);
if(strcmp($text,$lastArrayText["key"]) == 0){
    ..do something...
}
```

But when I switch to 5.4.x everything OK. Anyone tell me what is difference between PHP 5.3.x <=> 5.4.x when using this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is not in `end()` function.

Problem is in array dereferencing

```
strcmp($text,end($arrayText)["key"])
                            ^-- this syntax
```

As it was introduced in `php5.4`, read [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing), especially example **7**.

Comment: I see! perfect. Thank you very much!